# vim : copy one entire column from one file to another file

Tags: vim, kate

File #1:

```
F#1  A1  B1  C1
F#1  A2  B2  C2
F#1  A3  B3  C3
F#1  A4  B4  C4
F#1  A5  B5  C5
F#1  A6  B6  C6
```

File #2:

```
D1  E1  F1
D2  E2  F2
D3  E3  F3
D4  E4  F4
D5  E5  F5
D6  E6  F6
```

The wanted format in File#2:

```
F#1  D1  E1  F1
F#1  D2  E2  F2
F#1  D3  E3  F3
F#1  D4  E4  F4
F#1  D5  E5  F5
F#1  D6  E6  F6
```

In vim, how to copy the entire column (1st column in this example) from File #1 to File #2, as in the wanted format shown above? Note that, in reality, the file is very long.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Blockwise visual mode (`CTRL-v`) can help you achieving this (`:help v` for documentation).

The sequence of commands should be:

1. Go to the top-left corner.

[image]

2. Press `CTRL-v`. You should be in "VISUAL BLOCK" mode.

[image]

3. Press `G` - it will take you to the end of file.

[image]

4. Press `l` to mark the column (4 times in this case).

[image]

5. Press `y` to copy this column.
6. Open the second file (`:e <second-filename>`).
7. Go to the top left corner and press `P` to paste the column.